# How to remove deleted bot from my Telegram channel's admins?

Tags: console-application, telegram, telegram-bot

Recently I created a bot in Telegram and made it one of my channel's admins, after a while I deleted the bot using Botfather. Unfortunately I deleted the bot before removing it from my  channel's admin list. Now I can't Remove it. **Actually I press the remove button but the bot stays there. How can I remove it?**
To see how it looks like refer to the picture below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ai0X.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it will disappear itself after sometime. You may also contact Telegram Support, by Going to Settings -> Ask a Question. I'm sure the Telegram support guys will provide you the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll contact them.